# How to fix mesh topology to get bevel tool to work properly?

Tags: modeling

I have had this problem for a while, and have been kind of circumventing it while never finding a way to solve it. I am relatively new to blender, and have noticed that in some models, the bevel tool works differently on different edges. I can assume that this is due to different mesh topology, but I have yet to find a definitive fix to make the bevel modifier apply to the mesh evenly when it applies unevenly before. I'm no expert on 3d modeling, so any answers using relatively understandable terms for a novice would be nice.

Here is an example of the issue described; I have a crow's nest on a low-poly ship model I am making, and want certain edges to be beveled to add detail, only problem is that I end up with what is shown in the following picture when I try to bevel some of the outer edges:

[image]

and this is what it looked like beforehand:

[image]

I have already tried applying scale, toggling the bevel weight, and messing around with other various settings, but with no results.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Hi. It might be more likely for you to get help if you could upload a .blend file with this problem part in it to https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: From your second image, it looks as if you have overlapping edges as you can see with half of the right-hand line being hilighted orange and the other half in white. As @curious_1 says, we'll need to see your Blend file.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it. In future you can also create full-sized screenshots to upload via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu.

Comment: Please show us your topology, in Edit Mode, or with Wire-frame switched on in 'Properties > Object > Viewport Display' . One thing you may not have checked is Normals. Overlays > 'Face Orientation' .. everything should be blue.

Comment: here is the file for anyone who wants to diagnose the problem, I made the cuts that @Cornivius suggested, but the beveling is still wonky [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=E9Dng9O8" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/E9Dng9O8/)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, and it's what responsible for 90% of my problems in blender which is the face normals. Turns out the upper and front rows of faces had outside facing normals while the lower and back facing rows of faces had inside facing normals, making the bevel tool a bit confused as to which side of the face's edge to bevel.

Answer (score 0):

Bevels don't really work when you have edges connecting to an Ngon like that top face. For it to work properly you'd need edges here as well:
[image]

Alternatively, for this kind of low poly detail, you could just take the knife tool (K) And cut some edges on the red lines, then dissolve the green ones:
[image]